# Ruby on Rails not connecting to Table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using Ruby on Rails 4.0.0.

Over in app/controllers/api/v1/glossary_controller.rb:

```
class Api::V1::GlossaryController < ApplicationController
    def index
        render json: Glossary.all
    end
end
```

And in app/models/api/v1/glossary.rb:

```
class Api::V1::Glossary < ActiveRecord::Base
    table_name "glossary"

    @glossary = self.all
end
```

As well as app/models/api/v1.rb

```
module Api::V1
  def self.table_name_prefix
    'api_v1_'
  end
end
```

The route is as so:

```
Feta::Application.routes.draw do

  namespace :api, defaults: {format: 'json'} do
    namespace :v1 do
        get "glossary" => "glossary#index"
    end
  end

end
```

And the DB table is named "api_v1_glossary".

And the error: uninitialized constant Api::V1::Glossary::Glossary from glossary.rb in models when I define @glossary...

**EDIT:** I've updated from meager, but the problem of getting it to use glossary instead of glossaries persists. `@glossay.to_yaml` returns nothing. `@glossary` comes back `nil`.

Comment: '@glossary = Glossary.all' should be 'self.all', but i have no idea why you would want to do that in your model (outside of a method body)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what that `@glossary` line is supposed to do, but you need to refer to either `self` or `Api::V1::Glossary` there.

```
class Api::V1::Glossary < ActiveRecord::Base
    table_name = "glossary"

    @glossary = self.all
end
```

Comment: (facepalm...) knew it was something simple.

Comment: Its actually back to the original problem that I'm coming across. It is still looking for "glossaries" when I need it to look for "glossary".

Answer (score 0):

According to [RailsGuides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html#overriding-the-naming-conventions) you have to set the table name with `self.table_name = 'glossary'` but I am not sure if that is enough in the given example.